# How to configure SSL/HTTPS for Valhalla maps server?

Tags: ssl, maps, openstreetmap, tls1.2, mapserver

The Valhalla maps server docs assume that the server is always running on **"http://[hostname]:8002"**

*(see https://github.com/valhalla/valhalla)*

How can the server be configured to listen via **SSL/https** instead?
Is there any detailed documentation on how to do this?

Thnx.

Comment: I'd say, the web server used by Valhalla (https://github.com/kevinkreiser/prime_server) doesn't support HTTPS. Use nginx or Apache as reverse proxy instead.

Comment: Thnx. I actually came to a very similar conclusion/solution the next day after I posted the question :-)

Comment: Yep thats exactly right. The project does not support SSL/https as the built in [webserver](https://github.com/kevinkreiser/prime_server) does not support it. Classically people have worked around this by using a proxy which is often needed anyway as its a good place to put in user authentication or rate limiting and other business logic that is specific to a certain deployment.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

After much reading & research I came to the conclusion that a practical way to achieve this is simply to hide the Valhalla port (port 8002) behind my Linux firewall and to expose port 443 (SSL) instead and have Nginx running on that port. Nginx then port-forwards the Valhalla request obj to the internal port 8002 and proxies the response back to the caller for the return journey on the encrypted channel.
Setting up Nginx to achieve this is fairly straightforward and the procedure is documented on many websites.